# MPI - Difference between mpi_type_get_extent and mpi_type_get_true_extent

Tags: memory, fortran, mpi, sub-array

I have some problem in understanding the difference between `mpi_type_get_extent` and `mpi_type_get_true_extent`. In practice, I was using the former, expecting the results I then obtained with the latter, so I checked the [MPI 3.1 Standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report-book.pdf), where I found (at the section *4.1.8 True Extent of Datatypes*)

> However, the datatype extent cannot be used as an estimate of the
>   amount of space that needs to be allocated, **if the user has modified
>   the extent**

which made me think that I should have experienced no difference in the use of the two subroutines as long as I hadn't modified the extent of the datatype.

But I'm evidently missing something.

Declared the following MPI derived data type,

```
sizes    = [10,10,10]
subsizes = [ 3, 3, 3]
starts   = [ 2, 2, 2]
CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(ndims, sizes, subsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, newtype, ierr)
```

the following code

```
call mpi_type_size(newtype, k, ierr)
call mpi_type_get_extent(newtype, lb, extent, ierr)                                                                                             
call mpi_type_get_true_extent(newtype, tlb, textent, ierr)
write(*,*) k/DBS, lb/DBS, extent/DBS, tlb/DBS, textent/DBS ! DBS is the size of double precision
```

produces the output (obviously the same for all processes)

```
27   0   1000   222   223
```

So `mpi_type_size` behave like I expect, returning `PRODUCT(subsizes)*DBS` in `k`; on the other hand, I'd have expected from both `mpi_type_get_extent` and `mpi_type_get_true_extent` what only the latter returns (since I have not modified `newtype` at all), specifically `222 223`, which are basically `starts(1) + starts(2)*sizes(1) + starts(3)*sizes(1)*sizes(2)` and `1 + (subsizes - 1)*[1, sizes(1), sizes(1)*sizes(2)]`.

Why does `mpi_type_get_extent` return `0` and `PRODUCT(sizes)` in `lb` and `extent`, regardless of `subsizes` and `starts`?

I haven't posted an MWE since I have no errors at all (not at compile time, nor at runtime), I simply haven't got the way the two aforementioned routines work. I would basically like someone to help me in understanding the description of those subroutine in the standard document and why it is correct to obtain those result that I didn't expect.

**EDIT**
As requested by @GillesGouaillardet, I add a "minimal" working example to be run with **at least 4 processes** (please run it with exactly 4 processes, so that we have the same output), at the end of this question. The last lines can be uncommented (with awareness) to show that the types representing non-contiguous memory location work properly when used with `count > 1`, **once they've been properly resized** by means of `mpi_type_create_resized`. With those lines commented, the program prints `size`, `lb`, `extent`, `true_lb`, `true_extent` for all types created (even those intermediate, not committed):

```
 mpi_type_contiguous                    4                    0                    4                    0                    4
 mpi_type_vector                        4                    0                   13                    0                   13
 mpi_type_vector res                    4                    0                    1                    0                   13
 mpi_type_create_subarray               4                    0                   16                    0                   13
 mpi_type_create_subarray res           4                    0                    1                    0                   13
```

All types represent one row or column of a 4 by 4 matrix, so their `size` is predictably always `4`; the column type has `extent` and `true_extent` both equal to `4` units as well, since it represents four contiguous reals in memory; the type created with `mpi_type_vector` has `extent` and `true_extent` both equal to `13` reals, as I expected (see the nice sketch); if I want to use it with `count > 1`, I must resize it, changing its `extent` (and `true_extent` stays the same); now the hard part comes:

What is that `16` as `extent` of the type created with `mpi_type_create_subarray`? To be honest I'd have expected that routine to return an already resized type, ready to be used with `count > 1` (*i.e.* a type with `size = 4`, `extent = 1`, `true_extent = 13`), but it seems it does not: surprisingly for me, `extent` is `16`, which is the size of the global array!

The question is: why? Why the `extent` of a type created with `mpi_type_create_subarray` is the product of the elements of the `array_of_sizes` argument?

[image]

```
program subarray
use mpi
implicit none
integer :: i, j, k, ierr, myid, npro, rs, mycol, myrowugly, myrow_vec, myrow_sub
integer(kind = mpi_address_kind) :: lb, extent, tlb, textent
real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: mat
call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, myid, ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, npro, ierr)
allocate(mat(npro,npro))
mat = myid*1.0
call mpi_type_size(mpi_real, rs, ierr)

call mpi_type_contiguous(npro, mpi_real, mycol, ierr)
call mpi_type_commit(mycol, ierr)
call mpi_type_size(mycol, k, ierr)
call mpi_type_get_extent(mycol, lb, extent, ierr)
call mpi_type_get_true_extent(mycol, tlb, textent, ierr)
if (myid == 0) print *, 'mpi_type_contiguous         ', k/rs, lb/rs, extent/rs, tlb/rs, textent/rs

call mpi_type_vector(npro, 1, npro, mpi_real, myrowugly, ierr)
call mpi_type_size(myrowugly, k, ierr)
call mpi_type_get_extent(myrowugly, lb, extent, ierr)
call mpi_type_get_true_extent(myrowugly, tlb, textent, ierr)
if (myid == 0) print *, 'mpi_type_vector             ', k/rs, lb/rs, extent/rs, tlb/rs, textent/rs
call mpi_type_create_resized(myrowugly, int(0, mpi_address_kind)*rs, int(1, mpi_address_kind)*rs, myrow_vec, ierr)
call mpi_type_commit(myrow_vec, ierr)
call mpi_type_size(myrow_vec, k, ierr)
call mpi_type_get_extent(myrow_vec, lb, extent, ierr)
call mpi_type_get_true_extent(myrow_vec, tlb, textent, ierr)
if (myid == 0) print *, 'mpi_type_vector res         ', k/rs, lb/rs, extent/rs, tlb/rs, textent/rs

call mpi_type_create_subarray(2, [npro, npro], [1, npro], [0, 0], mpi_order_fortran, mpi_real, myrowugly, ierr)
call mpi_type_size(myrowugly, k, ierr)
call mpi_type_get_extent(myrowugly, lb, extent, ierr)
call mpi_type_get_true_extent(myrowugly, tlb, textent, ierr)
if (myid == 0) print *, 'mpi_type_create_subarray    ', k/rs, lb/rs, extent/rs, tlb/rs, textent/rs

call mpi_type_create_resized(myrowugly, int(0, mpi_address_kind)*rs, int(1, mpi_address_kind)*rs, myrow_sub, ierr)
call mpi_type_commit(myrow_sub, ierr)
call mpi_type_size(myrow_sub, k, ierr)
call mpi_type_get_extent(myrow_sub, lb, extent, ierr)
call mpi_type_get_true_extent(myrow_sub, tlb, textent, ierr)
if (myid == 0) print *, 'mpi_type_create_subarray res', k/rs, lb/rs, extent/rs, tlb/rs, textent/rs

!if (myid == 0) call mpi_send(mat(1,1), 2, mycol, 1, 666, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
!if (myid == 0) call mpi_recv(mat(1,3), 2, mycol, 1, 666, mpi_comm_world, mpi_status_ignore, ierr)
!if (myid == 1) call mpi_recv(mat(1,1), 2, mycol, 0, 666, mpi_comm_world, mpi_status_ignore, ierr)
!if (myid == 1) call mpi_send(mat(1,3), 2, mycol, 0, 666, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
!if (myid == 0) call mpi_send(mat(1,1), 2, myrow_vec, 1, 666, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
!if (myid == 0) call mpi_recv(mat(3,1), 2, myrow_vec, 1, 666, mpi_comm_world, mpi_status_ignore, ierr)
!if (myid == 1) call mpi_recv(mat(1,1), 2, myrow_vec, 0, 666, mpi_comm_world, mpi_status_ignore, ierr)
!if (myid == 1) call mpi_send(mat(3,1), 2, myrow_vec, 0, 666, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
!if (myid == 0) call mpi_send(mat(1,1), 2, myrow_sub, 1, 666, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
!if (myid == 0) call mpi_recv(mat(3,1), 2, myrow_sub, 1, 666, mpi_comm_world, mpi_status_ignore, ierr)
!if (myid == 1) call mpi_recv(mat(1,1), 2, myrow_sub, 0, 666, mpi_comm_world, mpi_status_ignore, ierr)
!if (myid == 1) call mpi_send(mat(3,1), 2, myrow_sub, 0, 666, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
!do i = 0, npro
!if (myid == i) then
!print *, ""
!print *, myid
!do j = 1, npro
!print *, mat(j,:)
!end do
!end if
!call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, ierr)
!end do

call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program subarray
```

Comment: (answer to the disappeared comment) I do not have errors, I simply don't understand whats wrong with my understanding of those two MPI tools, as applied to a user defined type, such as one created with `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY` (with a prefefined data type, such as `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`, there's no difference).

Comment: You don't have to answer deleted comments, there is a reason why I deleted it after all... By error I meant different results, but anyway, I deleted the comment. Your code is not directly compilable, but the necessary declarations are well predictable.

Comment: Regarding your edit (I repeat that my first comment is deleted so forget it), even programs that produce some result to be explained usually need a MWE, not just programs with errors but all other programs. Anyway, your code is probably fine and the declarations are predictable, that's why I deleted the comment.

Comment: long story short, `MPI_Type_create_subarray()` might modify the extent under the hood. In Fortran, a datatype that describes a column of a 2D square matrix ends up with `size==extent`, but a datatype that describes a row has the same size, but `extent` is the size of one element.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, what do you mean by _size of one element_? As far as I've read and seen, the `extent` of a type representing a row of a `m` by `n` Fortran matrix is `1+m*(n-1)`, and it's what I expected `mpi_type_get_extent` wouuld return.

Comment: You are mixing `extent` and `true_extent`. Feel free to `MPI_Send(matrix, 2, row_datatype, ...)` and when you get correct results, double check `extent` and `true_extent`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, indeed the title of the question is exactly _difference between [...]_.

Comment: what about writing a [MCVE] as I previously suggested ? You might want to write it in `C` and create a datatype for one column.

Comment: (I'm not a C programmer, it'd take to much to write it.) The link you suggested says, just after the title, _When asking a question about a problem caused by your code_; well, my code has no problem, my understanding of `extent` has problem, which I'm trying to solve here. Anyway I've added some compilable code which can be run.

Comment: Yes, the commented lines do that. I don't want to be repetitive, but the code **works**. **Properly**. It works because I appropriately resize the datatypes I create to represent non-contiguous memory locations. I'm just trying to understand what is the meaning of the `extent` that `mpi_type_create_subarray` confers to the type it creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Type_create_subarray()` creates a derived datatype whose extent is, per definition,  the product of all sizes.

The definition is in the MPI 3.1 standard at page 96.

`MPI_Type_create_subarray()` is generally used for MPI-IO, so this definition of the extent makes sense there.

It might not be what you wish in this very specific case, but think of a 2x2 subarray of a 4x4 array. What extent would you expect ?

Comment: So it is `(ub_marker, size0*ex)`, the last element of the typemap of eq. (4.2), to be "responsible", have I correctly understood?

Comment: Yes, this is my understanding

Comment: Oh, finally! I hope this question has given you the opportunity to reinforce your knowledge, as it helped me in improving mine. Btw, being the datatype in question a subarray `S` of an array `A`, I expected its `extent` to be equal either to its `true_extent` (which is a property of `S` as part of `A`, in which it "lives"), or, at least, to its `subsize` (which would be a property of `S` only), but not `size` which is a property of `A` only.